# Django 2 UserCreationForm not creating user

Tags: forms, python-3.x, django-views, django-2.0

I'm using django-email-as-username so users can authenticate without a username and use their email instead. It seems that when I try to register a new user, I'm redirected back to the form page and the user isn't created. Am I supposed to be including the cleaned_data in my view?

Any advice?

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import (authenticate, get_user_model,
                                 password_validation)
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from cuser.models import CUser

UserModel = get_user_model()


class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
    """
    Base class for authenticating users. Extend this to get a form that accepts
    email/password logins.
    """
    email = forms.EmailField(
        label=_("Email address"),
        max_length=254,
        widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'autofocus': True}),
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Password"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
    )

    error_messages = {
        'invalid_login': _(
            "Please enter a correct %(username)s and password. Note that both "
            "fields may be case-sensitive."
        ),
        'inactive': _("This account is inactive."),
    }

    def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        The 'request' parameter is set for custom auth use by subclasses.
        The form data comes in via the standard 'data' kwarg.
        """
        self.request = request
        self.user_cache = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.username_field = UserModel._meta.get_field(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)

    def clean(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        if email and password:
            self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, email=email, password=password)
            if self.user_cache is None:
                # An authentication backend may reject inactive users. Check
                # if the user exists and is inactive, and raise the 'inactive'
                # error if so.
                try:
                    self.user_cache = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(email)
                except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
                    pass
                else:
                    self.confirm_login_allowed(self.user_cache)
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    self.error_messages['invalid_login'],
                    code='invalid_login',
                    params={'username': self.username_field.verbose_name},
                )
            else:
                self.confirm_login_allowed(self.user_cache)

        return self.cleaned_data

    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        """
        Controls whether the given User may log in. This is a policy setting,
        independent of end-user authentication. This default behavior is to
        allow login by active users, and reject login by inactive users.
        If the given user cannot log in, this method should raise a
        ``forms.ValidationError``.
        If the given user may log in, this method should return None.
        """
        if not user.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['inactive'],
                code='inactive',
            )

    def get_user_id(self):
        if self.user_cache:
            return self.user_cache.id
        return None

    def get_user(self):
        return self.user_cache


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    A form that creates a user, with no privileges, from the given email and
    password.
    """
    error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': _("The two password fields didn't match."),
    }
    email = forms.EmailField(
        label=_("Email address"),
        max_length=254,
        widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'autofocus': True}),
    )
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Password"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html(),
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Password confirmation"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        strip=False,
        help_text=_("Enter the same password as before, for verification."),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = CUser
        fields = []

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                code='password_mismatch',
            )
        return password2

    def _post_clean(self):
        super()._post_clean()
        # Validate the password after self.instance is updated with form data
        # by super().
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password:
            try:
                password_validation.validate_password(password, self.instance)
            except forms.ValidationError as error:
                self.add_error('password2', error)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        label=_("Email address"),
        max_length=254,
        widget=forms.EmailInput(),
    )
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField(
        label=_("Password"),
        help_text=_(
            "Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see this "
            "user's password, but you can change the password using "
            "<a href=\"{}\">this form</a>."
        ),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = CUser
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password'].help_text = self.fields['password'].help_text.format('../password/')
        f = self.fields.get('user_permissions')
        if f is not None:
            f.queryset = f.queryset.select_related('content_type')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]
```

views.py

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from .forms import UserCreationForm

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("This will be the profile homepage.")


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from accounts import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
```

register.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div>
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <form method="post" action="">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at custom user [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)? Seems to mention exactly what you mentioned, but as a caveat it requires you to do it on the first migration